# python replace words based on occurance count

Tags: python, string, read-eval-print-loop

I am relatively new to python. I would want to replace a word which occurs more than twice with a different word. The words can consist of multiple numbers of words. I would want them to be replaced with XYZ. Example:

```
ABC is a tall person. ABC likes sports. Sports are good for health. ABC is a gold medalist in many sports.
```

ABC and sports should be replaced with XYZ. like, the sentence above should be:

```
XYZ is a tall person. XYZ likes XYZ. XYZ are good for health. XYZ is a gold medalist in many XYZ.
```

I used dictionary and was able to get to a point of counting the occurance of a word. However was not able to get the replacement right. I want to accomplish this using regex/for loop/data structures such as lists/dictionary. Is there a count based replacement function available upfront to accomplish this?

Comment: Please share your code of what you have been working on.

Comment: Post the part of your code where you are "not able to get the replacement right". This will help us figure out where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a dictionary, what you want is loop and check if the word appears twice or more and run string.replace(), usage example:

```
s = ABC is a tall person. ABC likes sports. Sports are good for health. ABC is a gold medalist in many sports.

s.replace("ABC", "XYZ")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of str.split() and str.replace() methods while checking them, for example

```
 b=a.split(' ',1)
 if(b.count(b[i])) > 1:
         b.replace(b[i],'XYZ')
```